# How to "weak link" to the Python framework on Mac OS X?

Tags: python, xcode, macos, pyobjc

I'm trying to create an app that can link to Mac OS X's built-in Python framework and have it work on Mac OS X 10.5, 10.6 and 10.7.

1. If I try to hard-link to the framework (the default), Leopard complains that he can't find 10.7.
2. If I try to weakly link the framework (using -weak_framework Python in the compiler flags),

In both cases, the Mac OS X deployment target is set to 10.5.

My main.m looks like this:

```
#import <Python/Python.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Py_SetProgramName("/usr/bin/python");
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import os; os.system('say okay')");
    return 0;
}
```

This program works on Mac OS X Lion but crashes on Mac OS X Leopard. It gives a "Exited abnormally: Bus error" with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS) exception (because it refers to address 0).

Is there any way to

A zip file of a test program is available here:

http://slurf.net/files/TheWeakestLink.zip

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do here but here are a few suggestions.  The only Python version common to the system Python frameworks in those three operating system releases is Python 2.5 so you *may* be able to explicitly target that version.  But, more likely, you would be better off packaging your own Python framework within your app.  If you are careful, you could use one of the [python.org 32-bit only installers](http://python.org/download/) for this purpose although it might be better to use one specifically built for 10.5+ especially if you need to build C extension modules for your app on 10.7.  [py2app](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2app/) can create a standalone Python app, by bundling up a non-system Python frameworks, with no need for an Objective C front-end.  Perhaps you can use it for your purposes.

Comment: I've had some success linking to 2.5 (since that is available everywhere). I'd like to link to a "generic" version of a Python, which would resolve at runtime to the latest version of Python available on the system. Is this possible?

Comment: In each Python Framework there is a `Current` symlink in the `Versions` directory.  But if you mean `linking` in the sense of object code linking, keep in mind that the Python project makes no guarantee of C level ABI compatibility between versions.  If you just want to invoke the newest Python interpreter, you should probably just use the links in `/usr/bin/python` or something.  Most third-party apps that I am aware of which use Python ship their own copy of Python within the app (using `py2app` or the equivalent).  It's too complicated otherwise.